# How to bind an empty collection object to a Data Grid?

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

How to bind an empty collection object to a Data Grid? When I bind it as below it is throwing "Object reference not set to an instance" error.

grid1.DataSource = new CollectionClass();
grid1.DataBind();

Comment: which line are you getting this error. Review stacktrace.

Comment: Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.JsTypeResolver.ResolveTypeId(Type type) +450
   Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.GridField.SaveClientProperties() +120
   Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.FormattedGridField.SaveClientProperties() +30
   Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.BoundDataField.SaveClientProperties() +29
 
Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.ObjectBase.Infragistics.Web.UI.IClientState.SaveClientProperties() +31

Comment: Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.ObjectBase.SaveObjectClientProperties(IClientState webObject, StringBuilder builder) +34
   Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.ObjectBase.WriteClientCollections(StringBuilder builder, ArrayList collections) +649
   Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.ObjectBase.SaveCollectionsStateToViewState() +165
   Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.RunBot.HandleSaveViewState() +82
   Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.Data.FlatDataBoundControl.SaveViewState() +108

Comment: Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.BaseGrid.SaveViewState() +69
   Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.WebDataGrid.SaveViewState() +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() +187
   System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() +106

Comment: Why didn't you include the stacktrace in the actual body of your post? Its hard to read like this...

Comment: Based on the exception, I am expecting that you have defined your fields in your aspx markup.  Does your CollectionClass derive from IEnumerable<T>?  If it doesn't, does making this change affect the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the instance of CollectionClass() and then bind to the Grid.

```
CollectionClass() cc = new CollectionClass();
grid1.DataSource = cc; 
grid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing in the above steps?